# How to connect paired dots in dodged dotplots with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several variables measured twice and I want to display them in a chart showing boxplots as well as individual values (using `geom_dotplot`) where the values from the two measurements in the same variable are connected by a customisable line.

I have found a solution using jittered `geom_point` (basically generating a new data) but if at all possible, I would like to have a dotplot.

Simplified code to create the chart for 5 subjects and 2 variables

```
library(ggplot2)


dat <- data.frame(subject     = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                  measurement = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2",
                                  "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2"), 
                  variable    = c("Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1",
                                  "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2"), 
                  value       = c(20, 15, 21, 23, 15, 22, 21, 31, 24, 17, 26, 10, 23, 22, 19, 29, 15, 25, 29, 19))


ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value, colour = measurement)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = measurement),
               binaxis = "y", binwidth = 0.5, stackdir = "center", 
               position = position_dodge(0.75))
```

The current chart where I would like to have lines connecting paired red and cyan dots between the two measurements within a variable, as shown for Var1 where I drawn them by hand:
[image]

Thanks, PB

Comment: Which points do you want to connect?

Comment: I want to connect the the two points for the same subjects from the two measurements (M1 and M2). For example, in Var1 it would be 20 and 22 for subject 1 and  15 and 21 for subject 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar output by using `facet_wrap` and specifying `aes(group = subject)`, so each gray line is an individual subject. I've provided two options, one split by variable and the other split by measurement. The second plot is probably closer to your original idea.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(subject     = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                  measurement = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2",
                                  "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2", "M2"), 
                  variable    = c("Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1",
                                  "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2"), 
                  value       = c(20, 15, 21, 23, 15, 22, 21, 31, 24, 17, 26, 10, 23, 22, 19, 29, 15, 25, 29, 19))

# split by measurement
dat %>% 
  mutate(new = factor(interaction(measurement, variable))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = new, y = value, color = measurement)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = measurement),
               binaxis = "y", binwidth = 0.5, stackdir = "center", 
               position = position_dodge(0.75)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subject), color = "gray") +
  facet_wrap(~measurement, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Var1", "Var2")) +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

```
# split by variable
dat %>% 
  mutate(new = factor(interaction(variable, measurement))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = new, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = variable),
               binaxis = "y", binwidth = 0.5, stackdir = "center", 
               position = position_dodge(0.75)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subject), color = "gray") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("M1", "M2")) + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the second plot is close to what I wanted.

Comment: (pressed Enter too soon in the comment above) However, the plot I posted is simplified, I need to facet the real plot by a different variable not presented in the example data (and have the same axis range for all variables and different colors for M1 and M2). Moreover, the lines seem to horizontally connect the actual points but the bin centers. I am very new to R/ggplot and thought this would be easy, but I guess not. Perhaps there is a way to get the x/y coordinates of the points somehow and use them for plotting the lines: I will try to dig deeper into the docs. Thanks again.